# Media Foundation vs DirectShow and Media Containers. (WEBM and OGG THEORA)

Tags: directshow, ogg, ms-media-foundation, webm

Why do all the new video/media container formats provide very little support for media foundation and more for DirectShow knowing that DirectShow is dying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because Media Foundation offers inferior feature set and availability to DirectShow. DirectShow is primary API for formats and codecs in Windows, nevertheless Microsoft stopped its development almost 10 years ago. The extensibility of this API is so good, and it is still so well applicable to multimedia tasks and processing.

Comment: I hope someone will create something like ffdshow or Haali as MediaSink and MediaTransform for MediaFoundation. Because with Windows8 MediaFoundation is the primary and only API you can use in Metro-Style Apps!