# How to preview/display video from bytes

Tags: c#, video-capture

How could I display/preview input video using Black Magic Design DecklinkAPI.dll? I could get video frame by frame but I do not know how could I display the frame in the Form/Window. I could implement IDeckLinkInputCallback:

```
void IDeckLinkInputCallback.VideoInputFrameArrived(IDeckLinkVideoInputFrame video,
    IDeckLinkAudioInputPacket audio)
{
    IntPtr pData;
    video.GetBytes(out pData);

    // What should I do to get the preview?

    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(video);
}
```

Another way I see is to implement IDeckLinkScreenPreviewCallback:

```
void IDeckLinkScreenPreviewCallback.DrawFrame(IDeckLinkVideoFrame theFrame)
{
    // Constructor: m_ph = new CDeckLinkDX9ScreenPreviewHelper();
    m_ph.SetFrame(theFrame);

    // Should I use this method instead to get the preview?

    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(theFrame);
}
```

There more complete code samples but they are still missing the important bit of code:
[blackmagic SDK in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355930/blackmagic-sdk-in-c-sharp).
BMD Decklink SDK documentation could be found [here](http://www.scribd.com/doc/59849048/Blackmagic-Decklink-SDK).

Thanks.

Comment: isn't this a question for BMD Decklink SDK tech support?

Comment: You are right Anthony contact them should be the 1st step. However, I have some experience with manufactures and they might just say they do not have any C# developer and the plain C# example is all they have ;) Even if this is not the case with BMD SO community has far wider range of knowledge then any manufacturer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using DeckLink SDK to capture video, then it is your responsibility to convert frames into format, which can be consumed by presentation API (GDI, GDI+, DirectShow, Media Foundation etc) - certain effort is expected here since you typically capture in non-RGB pixel format, and possibly at non-standard stride.

Alternatively, you can use DeckLink DirectShow video capture source which captures video and makes it available as a feed compatible with [DirectShow API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375454%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You can use standard components to preview and process video. You can build and control DirectShow graphs in C# through [DirectShow.NET library](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I am not sure which one of those presentation API to use. Do you have a "favourite"? DirectShow.NET seems to be a bit outdated. Still WPF MediaKit uses it (and MF) which might be the fastest and safest way to go. Thanks

Comment: [My personal favorite is DirectShow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12101195/media-foundation-vs-directshow-and-media-containers-webm-and-ogg-theora), but I am not pushing this. The only reason to use MF is that it's supported on most recent platforms where DirectShow is forcefully discontinued. DirectShow.NET is in good standing (with way more information/samples on it around), you might be confused by the fact that you don't see new development, but it's fine since the entire API and wrapper are just in stable state.